# How to remove already existing column name in column action in Material react table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table, material-table, material-react-table

I am using Material react table and in salary column the column action dropdown contains "Clear Filter" "Filter by Salary" and I want to remove those columns so using "renderColumnActionsMenuItems" but new menu items are added but the old ones are not getting removed.

[image: Screenshot of the table]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MaterialReactTable from 'material-react-table';
import {MenuItem} from '@material-ui/core'


function Table() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    { header: "id", accessorKey: "id" },
    { header: "First Name", accessorKey: "FirstName" },
    { header: "Country", accessorKey: "Country" },
    {
      accessorKey: 'salary',
      header: 'Salary',
      renderColumnActionsMenuItems: ({ closeMenu,table}) => {
        return [
          <>
          <MenuItem
            onClick={() => {
              // do something
              closeMenu();
            }}
          >
            Custom Menu Item 1
          </MenuItem>,
          </>
        ];
      },
    },
  ];
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3030/")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        setData(resp["data"]);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <MaterialReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}    
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can get rid of all actions except show/hide.
Seems like there is no props to hide the "hide/show" but you can disable it.

You can add these options to your column config.

```
  enableColumnFilter: false,
  enableGlobalFilter: false,
  enableColumnOrdering: false,
  enableColumnFilterModes: false,
  enableHiding: false // Still displayed but at least disabled
```

Here is the list of all available props for a column

https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/api/column-options#renderColumnFilterModeMenuItems-column-option